# Scrapy and incomplete data, how do I store everything correctly?

Tags: html, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm still a beginner with Scrapy, but this problem really got me scratching my head. I've got a webstore from which I need to extract data. The data is all on one page, but most of the time incomplete.  It always has a name, but not always an amount or a description. It's structured in repeating classes [like this](https://pastebin.com/eFrbmHcN). Note that this example has all three datafields filled.

I need:

- The product name, located in < h4 class="mod-article-tile__title">
- The product amount, located in < span class="price__unit">
- The product description, located in < div class="mod-article-tile__info">

I managed to extract the data I need like this:

```
import pprint
import scrapy

class BasicSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = 'aldi'
  allowed_domains = ['aldi.nl']
  base_url = 'https://www.aldi.nl/onze-producten/a-merken.html'
  start_urls = ['https://www.aldi.nl/onze-producten/a-merken.html']

  def parse(self, response):
    products = response.xpath('//*[@class="mod-article-tile__content"]').extract()
    name = response.xpath('//*[@class="mod-article-tile__title"]/text()').extract()
    amount = response.xpath('//*[@class="price price--50 price--right mod-article-tile__price"]/text()').extract()
    info = response.xpath('//*[@class="mod-article-tile__info"]/p/text()').extract()

    i = 0
    for product in products:
      pprint.pprint(name[i] + " : " + amount[i] + ", " + info[i])
      i+=1
```

However, this doesn't take incomplete data into account. So now since not all lists have the same length, an IndexError is thrown, and the data isn't assigned correctly. I tried parsing it using product, but I can't use xpath on it afterwards because it's a string.

So, is there a way to use xpath on the string result, or another way to extract the data from product? Or should I rather look into checking if the parsed data is empty, and insert empty data there?

Oh, and also, I can't seem to remove the pesky \n\t's that appear everywhere. I tried

```
def clean_string(self, string):
    result = string.replace('\\n', '')
    result = result.replace('\\t', '')
    return result.strip()
```

But it didn't do the trick. Anyone able to drop a hint to resolve that?

Comment: is this your whole spider?

Comment: Yes, this is the spider file.

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#nesting-selectors